# He turned up one night stone broke in Medellín

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> My father was a renegade priest. I don’t know if he was Colombian or came from some other country. But he was Latin American. **He turned up one night stone broke in Medellín**, preaching sermons in bars and whorehouses. Some people thought he was working for the secret police, but my mother kept him from getting killed and took him to her penthouse in the neighborhood. They lived together for four months, I’ve been told, and then my father vanished into the Gospels.

This is an excerpt from Roberto Bolaño's 'The Return', a short story, I just want to understand the meaning of the sentence in bold. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Which part of the sentence is causing you trouble?

Comment: Unfair to close...if it ain't a dupe, and does not show on a casual search, it belongs here.

Comment: You can quickly search that "turned up" means arrived, or showed up. The only other phrase that might be hard to understand would be "stone broke", but from a quick search, it means entirely without money.

Comment: I think many are missing the point of this Q. This is a use  of "stone" as an intensifier as in 'stone cold', 'stone dead' , 'stone deaf', 'stone killer' etc in AmE. Vote to re-open, based on edits to show basic research.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence means "One night, he arrived [turned up] in Medellin with no money at all [stone broke]."

[lexico *turn up*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/turn_up)
2 Put in an appearance; arrive.

[Merriam-Webster *stone broke*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stone%20broke)
: without any money at all

The word *broke* means having no money. The word *stone* intensifies that.

Comment: Not a suitable question for ELU.

Comment: Oh Great! Thank you very much Jack.

Comment: I know that 'stone' is often used as an intensifier in US English, but in Britain we'd be more likely to say 'stony' to intensify 'broke', although we can sometimes use 'stone' as an intensifier in other situations.

Comment: I think, now, that in UK English, we tend to say that a person or a thing is 'stone [something]' when they or it share a quality with stone, e.g. stone blind, stone deaf, stone cold (there is a song called 'Stone Cold Dead in the Market'), stone dead. Using 'stone' as a general intensifier (e.g. stone crazy') seems to be a US thing.

Comment: Well, stones don't have much money...